# Most efficient algorithm to filter dataframe based on two nested conditions in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe, performance

Im currently working with a really large dataframe (~2M rows) about "landings" and "takes off". With some information like the time the operation happened, in which airport, where was it heading and so on.

What I want to do is to filter the whole DF into a new one that just consider "flights", so about half the entries matching each take off with its corresponding landing based on the airport codes of the origin airport and the destination airport.

What I did, that works but considering how large the DF it takes about 200 hours to complete is

```
Loop on all rows of DF checking for some df$Operation=="takeoff"{
     Loop on all rows, below the row found before, for df$operation="ladning" 
     where codes of origin and destination airport match the "take off" entry{
          Once found i add the data i need to the new df called Flights
     }
}
```

(If the second loop does not find a match in the next 100 rows it discards the entry and searchs for the next "take off")

Is there a function that perfoms this operation in a more efficient way? If not, do you know of an algorithm that could be way faster than the one i did?

I am really not used to data science, nor R. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That makes sense. On SO, tags should be used to describe what your question is about. It appears you are looking to process a dataframe with R and are looking for a solution in R. For these reasons, I've removed the `pandas` tag.

Comment: It's strongly preferred to provide a working reproducible example rather than pseudocode.  That way people can benchmark solutions and ensure that they provide the correct output, among other benefits. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: In R we try to avoid using loops. For filtering a dataframe I would use the filter functio in dplyr. dplyr is great and easy and fast for working with dataframes. If it's still not fast enough you can try data.table, but it's a bit less user friendly.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining what your data looks like. Can you please include a sample, or data that looks like it? Often easiest for you and us if you can include the output of `dput(head(df))` in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

In R we try to avoid using loops. For filtering a dataframe I would use the filter function in dplyr. dplyr is great and easy and fast for working with dataframes. If it's still not fast enough you can try data.table, but it's a bit less user friendly.

This does what you want I think.

```
library(dplyr)

flights <- df %>% 
  arrange(datetime) %>% # make sure the data is in the right order
  group_by(origin, destination) %>% # for each flight path
  dplyr::filter(Operation %in% c("takeoff", "landing")) # get these rows
```

I recommend the online book R For Data Science:
https://r4ds.had.co.nz/